# Catching IDisposables that are never disposed

Tags: c#, dispose

So, as a new .NET programmer I thought that the garbage collector would clean up my mess for me all the time.

Now, a year and a half later I am getting out of memory exceptions in that code I wrote when I did not know that I had to call dispose on some resources.  I am guessing that is because that code allocats a lot of bitmaps that don't get disposed...

I have gone through the code to clean these up now that I know better.  But I keep missing some.  Is there a tool or setting that can see IDisposables not getting disposed?

While I can see the simple cases being easy to catch by compiler or tool, I can also see some more complex scenarios being very hard to catch.  So if there is no tool I understand and will keep doing it by hand.

Comment: Don't panic.  Only bitmaps really count, search your codebase for "Image" and "Bitmap".  Controls do too but you can see that (permanent) leak easily with Task manager.  That will be good for another couple of years, you can chip away at the rest of them at your convenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at FxCop. [One of its rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx) will catch items that implement `IDisposable`, where `Dispose()` wasn't called.

Answer (score 1):

A memory profiler will be able to show you where all live objects of a given class where allocated from - this can be a good starting point.

Some of the memory profiler now claim to track missing calls to Dispose(), - I don't know how well they work.

Comment: One such profiler that should be in the .NET SDK is the CLR Profiler. I believe it reports the number of unreleased handles at the end function call.